# How does converting an integer to a byte array work in C#

Tags: c#, math, binary

I am aware of bytes and bits and how computers use the base 2 (binary) number system.

I am however struggling to understand how a 32-bit (4 byte) integer is represented in a byte array.

```
    int exampleInt = 270;

    byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(exampleInt);
    // intBytes = [14, 1, 0, 0]
```

What does 14 and 1 represent? I know a byte can be between 0 and 255.

A breakdown of these numbers and 4 bytes would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, 270 in binary is `100001110`. If we add some 0s to make it 32 bits, it looks like this:

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 00001110
```

I have grouped the bits into bytes for clarity. `00001110` is 14 in binary, and `00000001` is 1 in binary. And because the system uses little [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), the least significant byte - 14 - goes first.